# Windows XAMPP webserver not handling nested quotes

Tags: php, web-server, xampp

I'm having problems with third party HTML on a XAMPP based development webserver. The code produces garbage in the browser because it is filled with dubious nested quotes as follows...

```
<a href="$Link" title="<% sprintf(_t("READMORE","Click here to read more on &quot;%s&quot;"),$CartTitle.XML) %>">...</a>
```

I either need a script to bulk fix script so the code is like this (send me to Stack Overflow?):

```
<a href="$Link" title="<% sprintf(_t('READMORE','Click here to read more on &quot;%s&quot;'),$CartTitle.XML) %>">...</a>
```

OR a better understanding of the problem and a workaround because obviously other webservers handle this just fine.

This is Silverstripe (php) with asp style tags in it's templates, if that is relevant. I think it is a *nix vs windows problem but the keywords I search ("nested quotes?") produce nothing. Worse still, I know I've fixed this before! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a Silverstripe specific problem with sprintf on windows XAMPP.

http://www.silverstripe.org/dataobjectmanager-module-forum/show/9482?start=32#post293190